# Powershell script keep deleting &apos; entity

Tags: powershell

I have made a powershell script to edit multiple xml file in a folder,
it will edit only the "description" node but for some reason the final result is that the `&apos;` entity became a normal `'` and the "cloneof" node is splitted in two lines.

```
Get-ChildItem .\ *.xml -recurse | % {
echo "Editing file" $_.Name
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.fullname)
$xml.SelectNodes("//description") | ForEach-Object {
$string = $_.InnerText

if ($string -like "*(*") {
    $string = $string.substring(0, $string.Indexof("(")-1)

    if ($string -like '*,*') 
        {
        $article = $string.Substring($string.LastIndexOf(','))

        if ([string]$article -eq ", The") {
            $string = $article.Substring(2) + " " + $string.Substring(0, $string.LastIndexOf(","))
        }
        elseif ([string]$article -eq ", A") {
            $string = $article.Substring(2) + " " + $string.Substring(0, $string.LastIndexOf(","))
        }
        elseif ([string]$article -eq ", L'") {
            $string = $article.Substring(2) + $string.Substring(0, $string.LastIndexOf(","))
        }
        elseif ([string]$article -like "*-*") {
            $string = $article.Substring(2, $article.IndexOf("-")-2) + $string.Substring(0, $string.LastIndexOf(",")) + $article.substring($article.IndexOf("-")-1)
        }


      else {
            echo "No article renaming needed for:"
            echo $article
            echo $string
           }

        }
    }

$_.'#text' = $string
} 
$xml.save($_.FullName)
}
```

some ideas? teorically the rest of the file will remain untouched right?

the XML is full of section like this 
ORIGINAL XML

```
<game name="Addams Family, The - Pugsley&apos;s Scavenger Hunt (USA)" index="" image="">
    <description>Addams Family, The - Pugsley&apos;s Scavenger Hunt (USA)</description>
    <cloneof></cloneof>
    <crc>6B8D777D</crc>
    <manufacturer>Ocean</manufacturer>
    <year>1993</year>
    <genre>Platform</genre>
    <rating>Other - NR (Not Rated)</rating>
    <enabled>Yes</enabled>
</game>
```

EDITED XML

```
<game name="Addams Family, The - Pugsley's Scavenger Hunt (USA)" index="" image="">
<description>The Addams Family - Pugsley's Scavenger Hunt</description>
<cloneof>
</cloneof>
<crc>6B8D777D</crc>
<manufacturer>Ocean</manufacturer>
<year>1993</year>
<genre>Platform</genre>
<rating>Other - NR (Not Rated)</rating>
<enabled>Yes</enabled>
```

Comment: Why is it a problem that `&apos;` is changed? A regular `'` is fine in XML. Also, I don't see it in your example, nor do I understand what's the results for `<cloneof>`. Looks all fine to me... (Maybe add some **small** "before", "after" and "expected" examples?)

Comment: And is `<cloneof>` always empty in the original file when splitted in two lines?

Comment: My fault, the script are working the problem i list previously are only aesthetic since i would to leave untouched the rest of the xml.
Yes the cloneof node empty but it come in two line... it remain in a single line if the node as some text inside
I will put an exmple in the first post to be much clear :D